# Why triggered method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I create REACT component and passes the method to call by pressing the button, using the Redux connect. There is a code:

```
const PageClientOne = ({onSubmit, onDelete, client}) => {
    return(
        <form style={styles.enter} onSubmit={_handleSubmit(client,onSubmit)}>
        // ... something code

            <Button type="submit" theme="success">Save</Button>
            <Button type="button"
                            theme="error" onClick={onDelete(client._id)}>Delete</Button>
        </form>
    )
}

const _handleSubmit = (client, onSubmit) => {
    return event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        onSubmit(client)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        client: state.reducers.clientsState.client
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSubmit: (client) => {
        dispatch(saveClient(client))
    },
    onDelete: (id) => {
        console.log("DELETE")
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(PageClientOne)
```

The problem is that onDelete triggered when the page loads, and not only when clicked on the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *Why called method?* **IDK** :-p but please phrase `title` of question properly as its very important part of question. An unclear `title` will loose attention of most of people as you are asking them to read through description and code just to understand the issue.

Comment: @Rajesh I agree, although it's good to remember that for many people on SO, English isn't their first language.

Comment: It seems to me PageClientOne is a pure function, in this case life your state or props to the parent component,  onclick fire the parent component function to re-render the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its slightly different in React.

Change this,

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={onDelete(client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```

to,

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={()=>onDelete(client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```

Read here for more info,

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not very familiar with React, so this could be wrong...)

When you create your `<form>` element, you define the button like this:

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={onDelete(client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```

Code in brackets – `{onDelete(client._id)}` – gets executed *when the element is created* (at page load), and the *result it evaluates to* is inserted into the element, not the code itself. You meant to have a normal `onclick` attribute; so put the code in quotes `""` as in usual HTML:

```
onclick="onDelete(client._id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in onClick

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={onDelete(client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```

Instead of passing the callback function you are actually calling onDelete at the time of element creation.

Try

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={onDelete.bind(this, client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is corresponding to your question.
Looks like your delete button was submitting the form as you get the page refreshed.
So, you need to prevent the submit.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSubmit: (client) => {
        dispatch(saveClient(client))
    },
    onDelete: (evt, id) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        console.log("DELETE")
    }
}
```

And on your delete button

```
<Button type="button" theme="error" onClick={(evt) => onDelete(evt, client._id)}>Delete</Button>
```